# create a simple randomness feature in solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a for loop form range 1 to 4951 like this in solidity

```
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
```

I need to implement randomness in this loop such that the number is chosen between 1 to 4951 and doesnt repeat itself again and the supply increment by the total number selected

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow works best when you try stuff, it doesn't work, you share the code, and *then* we comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

If the number that you need to be generated at random is _minAmount check chainlink, that way you can get a good source of randomness,see more here https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/ and here https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/